# Auto generate data by tapping on a TextView in android

Tags: android

My application is similar to Google Search Engine. I need to generate a list of items from the database `SQLite` when a user clicks on the `TextView` without typing a single letter. I have worked on `AutoCompleteTextView` which takes 3 letters to generate the related text.

But I don't want the user to type anything. The user can just tap on `TextView` and click on the options. Please suggest some good websites to get help. I am using android 3.0 API=11
Thanks in advance..

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  How to generate the list of options or how to display it?  Or how to intercept the user's click on the text field?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618409/android-autocompletetextview-with-default-suggestions

Comment: Thanx nandeesh,dis exactly vat i was looking for..thank u once again